# Getting a phpmailerException error due to my attachments when my plugin runs

Tags: plugin-development, emails

When my plugin runs, I'm getting a PHP Mailer Exception error stating:

*"Could not access file: http://s3.amazonaws.com/patternmanager/clients/healthstream/question-attachments/download.jpeg"*

The url being pulled in is correct, and the file exists. I'm still very new to this, but the best I can figure out is that this is some kind of permissions issue?

Is there something in my code that might be causing a problem? Am I calling in the attachments correctly? Any direction is greatly appreciated.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    //Event: onSaveEntry
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event)
    {

        $entry = $event->params['entry'];
        $isNewEntry = $event->params['isNewEntry'];
        $entrySection = $entry->section;

        $attachments = $entry->questionAttachments;

        if ($isNewEntry and $entrySection == 'Questions')  {
            //Get all users from UserGroup
            $user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
            $user_criteria->groupId = '9';
            $users = $user_criteria->find();

            //Send to each User
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                //Send Mail
                $email = new EmailModel();
                $email->toEmail = $user->email;
                $email->subject = 'New Question';
                $email->htmlBody    =

                'A new question has been posted: <a href="'.$entry->url.'" title="'.$entry->title.'">'.$entry->title.'</a>';

                if ($attachments) {
                    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                        $email->addAttachment($attachment->url, $attachment->filename, 'base64', $attachment->kind);
                    }
                }

                craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) is only going work with local files for attachments, so you'll need to download the file from S3 into a known location, and pass that location in as the first parameter to `addAttachment`.